# Can I use 'AS' in 'BETWEEN' statement in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Can I use `as` in `BETWEEN` statement in mysql or something alike.

`SELECT * FROM status
WHERE date BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-01 00:00:00','GMT','UTC')
AND CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-07 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS firstweek 
AND date BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-08 00:00:00','GMT','UTC')
AND CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-15 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS secondweek
AND date BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-16 00:00:00','GMT','UTC')
AND CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-22 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS secondweek
ORDER BY date DESC`

I'm getting a syntax error.How can use an alias using `BETWEEN`?
Is there other way for naming each week, this will serve as my identifier.

Comment: Really? What will be the meaning of this? I'm lost with this now :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM date JOIN
    (SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-01 00:00:00','GMT','UTC') AS w1start,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-07 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS w1end,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-08 00:00:00','GMT','UTC') AS w2start,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-15 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS w2end,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-16 00:00:00','GMT','UTC') AS w3start,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-22 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS w3end) AS weeks
    WHERE date BETWEEN w1start AND w1end
       OR date BETWEEN w2start AND w2end
       OR date BETWEEN w3start AND w3end
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

This is at least a start.

If, however, you want to tell the application which of the 3 conditions is fulfilled, yiu might want to do

```
SELECT date BETWEEN w1start AND w1end AS firstweek, 
       date BETWEEN w2start AND w2end AS secondweek,
       date BETWEEN w3start AND w3end AS thirdweek,
       whatevercolumsyouneed
       FROM date JOIN
    (SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-01 00:00:00','GMT','UTC') AS w1start,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-07 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS w1end,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-08 00:00:00','GMT','UTC') AS w2start,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-15 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS w2end,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-16 00:00:00','GMT','UTC') AS w3start,
            CONVERT_TZ('2013-11-22 23:59:59','GMT','UTC') AS w3end) AS weeks
    HAVING firstweek OR secondweek OR thirdweek
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

(untested; I am not sure if `HAVING` is placed correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

You're putting an alias to the expression, not selected columns
You should make ir like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM  
(SELECT s.*, CONVERT(...) as field1, CONVERT(...) as field2 from status) t
...then do what you want with fieldsXX...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `AS` in the `WHERE` clause. It can only be used in the column list and in the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT a.somefield AS s, someexpr AS e
  FROM table1 AS a, ...
  WHERE ...
```